# How to use less space for ~

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

In a paper, I need to use the abbreviated form of Figure as in "see Fig. 2". To avoid line breaks between Fig. and the number itself, I place a `~` in between. However in that case, the inserted space is way too much and a `\,` looks a lot better.

So the question is, how can I protect the Figure expressions from line breaks but also reduce the space to `\,`?

Comment: It all depends on how you realize the construction. A MWE is needed.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\,` is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{%
   \relax\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\thinspace\fi
}
\def\thinspace{\kern .16667em }
```

Thus it is basically a `\kern`. It is not followed by glue, therefore there is no line break caused by `\,` in:

```
see~Fig.\,2
```

A fast test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \parbox{0pt}{%
    \hspace{0pt}% allow hyphenation for the first word
    see~Fig.\,2
  }
\end{document}
```

As expected, there is an overfull `\hbox` warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (38.80566pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--9
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 see Fig.2
```

And the line is unbroken:

> [image: Result]

Comment: Note that ``\,`` can bite: a user wanted to add it *in front* of words (I don't really know why); if that word was at the beginning of a paragraph, the kern was added as a *vertical* space, because of how `\kern` works. In this case it's safe, though, because it will always be preceded by a character.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed explanation clearing my foggy understanding of TeX's internals.

Comment: @egreg -- the `\kern` at the beginning of a paragraph detects that it's in vertical mode, and that's how the kern is applied.  like `\hbox` in that location, it doesn't switch into horizontal, but remains in vertical mode, usually causing the user to scratch his/her head in (at least momentary) confusion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, that's the problem. I thought it worthy mentioning. The definition of `\thinspace` should include `\leavevmode`, as it's documented as a text command.

Comment: @egreg: I am afraid that is one of the many issues that will never been fixed in frozen LaTeX2e.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I know; probably I should have said "the definition of `\thinspace` should have included `\leavevmode`".

Comment: @egreg perhaps something for `fixltx2e` ?